# urdf model (depth data is being shown in the wrong place in Rviz and non fixed joint not published)

Tags: ros

I am a beginner in ROS and related issues. I create a URDF model of my desired robot that has a depth camera. I have 2 questions:

1. Robot simulated correctly in gazebo but when I add some interest object in gazebo environment, I found that my camera sensor frame is wrong and it view direction is z axis of the robot. I read some related problem but I could fix it.
2. I use of plugin for skid driver, but my robot wheels' not published in rviz, when I checked robot model or rqt_garph I could see the wheels.

Could you please help me regarding them?

It is my urdf:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="bluebot" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
    <!-- base information-->
    <xacro:property name="base_length" value="0.50" />
    <xacro:property name="base_width" value="0.40" />
    <xacro:property name="base_height" value="0.10" />
    <xacro:property name="base_mass" value="14" />

    <!-- wheel information-->
    <xacro:property name="wheel_length" value="0.08" />
    <xacro:property name="wheel_radius" value="0.10" />
    <xacro:property name="wheel_mass" value="4.70" />

    <!-- camera_stand information-->
    <xacro:property name="camera_stand_length" value="0.10" />
    <xacro:property name="camera_stand_radius" value="0.05" />
    <xacro:property name="camera_stand_mass" value="2.50" />

    <!-- camera information-->
    <xacro:property name="camera_length" value="0.15" />
    <xacro:property name="camera_width" value="0.03" />
    <xacro:property name="camera_height" value="0.02" />
    <xacro:property name="camera_mass" value="1" />

    <xacro:property name="Pi" value="3.1415" />

    <!--inertial-->
    <xacro:macro name="solid_cuboid_inertial"  params="length width height mass">
        <inertial>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <mass value="${mass}"/>
            <inertia
                ixx="${(mass / 12) * ((base_height * base_height) + (base_length * base_length))}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
                iyy="${(mass / 12) * ((base_width * base_width) + (base_length * base_length))}" iyz="0.0"
                izz="${(mass / 12) * ((base_width * base_width) + (base_height * base_height))}"/>
        </inertial>
    </xacro:macro>

    <xacro:macro name="cylinder_inertial"  params="mass radius height">
        <inertial>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <mass value="${mass}"/>
            <inertia
                ixx="${(mass / 12) * ((3 * (radius * radius)) + ( height * height))}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
                iyy="${(mass / 12) * ((3 * ( radius* radius)) + ( height * height))}" iyz="0.0"
                izz="${(mass / 12) * (radius * radius)}"/>
        </inertial>
    </xacro:macro>

    <!--base_link-->
    <link name="base_link">
        <visual>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 ${base_height / 2}"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="${base_length} ${base_width} ${base_height}"/>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="${base_length} ${base_width} ${base_height}"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:solid_cuboid_inertial length="${base_length}" width="${base_width}" height="${base_height}" mass="${base_mass}"/>
    </link>

    <gazebo reference="base_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
    </gazebo>

    <!--wheel-->
    <xacro:macro name="wheel" params="name reflect1 reflect2">

        <link name="${name}_wheel_link">
            <visual>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder length ="${wheel_length}" radius="${wheel_radius}"/>
                </geometry>
            </visual>
            <collision>
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder length="${wheel_length}" radius="${wheel_radius}"/>
                </geometry>
            </collision>
            <xacro:cylinder_inertial mass="${wheel_mass}" radius="${wheel_radius}" height="${wheel_length}" />
        </link>

        <gazebo reference="${name}_wheel_link">
            <material>Gazebo/Gray</material>
            <mu1 value="10.0"/>
            <mu2 value="20.0"/>
        </gazebo>


        <joint name="${name}_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
            <parent link="base_link"/>
            <child link="${name}_wheel_link"/>
            <origin rpy="${Pi / 2} 0 0" xyz="${reflect2 * ((base_width / 2) + (wheel_length / 2))} ${reflect1 * base_length / 2} 0"/>
            <axis xyz="0 0 -1"/>
        </joint>

        <transmission name="${name}_wheel_transmission">
            <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
            <actuator name="${name}_wheel_motor">
                <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
            </actuator>
            <joint name="${name}_wheel_joint">
                <!-- <hardwareInterface>VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface> -->
                <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            </joint>
        </transmission>
    </xacro:macro>
    <xacro:wheel name="right_front" reflect1="1" reflect2="1" />
    <xacro:wheel name="left_front" reflect1="-1" reflect2="1" />
    <xacro:wheel name="right_back" reflect1="1" reflect2="-1" />
    <xacro:wheel name="left_back" reflect1="-1" reflect2="-1" />




    <!--camera_stand-->
    <link name="camera_stand_link">
        <visual>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="${camera_stand_length}" radius="${camera_stand_radius}"/>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="${camera_stand_length}" radius="${camera_stand_radius}"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:cylinder_inertial mass="${camera_stand_mass}" radius="${camera_stand_radius}" height="${camera_stand_length}" />
    </link>
    <gazebo reference="camera_stand_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
    </gazebo>
    <joint name="camera_stand_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="camera_stand_link"/>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="${base_width / 2} 0 ${(base_length / 2) - 0.10}"/>
    </joint>

    <!--camera-->
    <link name="camera_link">
        <visual>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="${camera_length} ${camera_width} ${camera_height}"/>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="${camera_length} ${camera_width} ${camera_height}"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:solid_cuboid_inertial length="${camera_length}" width="${camera_width}" height="${camera_height}" mass="${camera_mass}"/>
    </link>
    <gazebo reference="camera_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Yellow</material>
    </gazebo>

    <joint name="camera_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="camera_link"/>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${Pi / 2}" xyz="${base_width / 2} 0 ${base_length / 2}"/>
    </joint>


    <link name="camera_sensor_link"/>

    <joint name="camera_sensor_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="camera_link"/>
        <child link="camera_sensor_link"/>
        <origin rpy="${-3 * Pi/2} ${Pi/2} ${Pi/2}" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <!-- <origin rpy="${3*Pi/2} 0 ${Pi}" xyz="0 0 0"/> -->
    </joint>

    <gazebo reference="camera_sensor_link">
        <sensor type="depth" name="xtion_pro">       
            <always_on>true</always_on>
            <visualize>true</visualize>             
            <camera>
                <horizontal_fov>1.047</horizontal_fov>
                <image>
                    <width>640</width>===
                    <height>480</height>
                    <format>R8G8B8</format>
                </image>
                <depth_camera>
                </depth_camera>
                <clip>
                    <near>0.1</near>
                    <far>10</far>
                </clip>
            </camera>
            <plugin name="camera_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so">
                <baseline>0.2</baseline>
                <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
                <!-- Keep this zero, update_rate in the parent <sensor> tag
                    will control the frame rate. -->
                <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
                <cameraName>camera_ir</cameraName>
                <imageTopicName>/camera/color/image_raw</imageTopicName>
                <cameraInfoTopicName>/camera/color/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
                <depthImageTopicName>/camera/depth/image_raw</depthImageTopicName>
                <depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>/camera/depth/camera_info</depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>
                <pointCloudTopicName>/camera/depth/points</pointCloudTopicName>
                <frameName>camera_sensor_link</frameName>
                <pointCloudCutoff>0.5</pointCloudCutoff>
                <pointCloudCutoffMax>3.0</pointCloudCutoffMax>
                <distortionK1>0</distortionK1>
                <distortionK2>0</distortionK2>
                <distortionK3>0</distortionK3>
                <distortionT1>0</distortionT1>
                <distortionT2>0</distortionT2>
                <CxPrime>0</CxPrime>
                <Cx>0</Cx>
                <Cy>0</Cy>
                <focalLength>0</focalLength>
                <hackBaseline>0</hackBaseline>
            </plugin>
        </sensor>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo>
        <plugin name="skid_steer_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_skid_steer_drive.so">
            <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
            <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace>
            <leftFrontJoint>left_front_wheel_joint</leftFrontJoint>
            <rightFrontJoint>right_front_wheel_joint</rightFrontJoint>
            <leftRearJoint>left_back_wheel_joint</leftRearJoint>
            <rightRearJoint>right_back_wheel_joint</rightRearJoint>
            <wheelSeparation>0.4</wheelSeparation>
            <wheelDiameter>${wheel_radius * 2}</wheelDiameter>
            <robotBaseFrame>base_link</robotBaseFrame>
            <torque>20</torque>
            <topicName>cmd_vel</topicName>
            <broadcastTF>false</broadcastTF>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo>
        <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
        <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>
</robot>
```

and it is my launch file:

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <launch>

    <!-- these are the arguments you can pass this launch file, for example paused:=true -->
    <arg name="paused" default="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" default="true"/>
    <arg name="extra_gazebo_args" default=""/>
    <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
    <arg name="recording" default="false"/>
    <!-- Note that 'headless' is currently non-functional.  See gazebo_ros_pkgs issue #491 (-r arg does not disable
        rendering, but instead enables recording). The arg definition has been left here to prevent breaking downstream
        launch files, but it does nothing. -->
    <arg name="headless" default="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" default="false"/>
    <arg name="physics" default="ode"/>
    <arg name="verbose" default="false"/>
    <arg name="output" default="screen"/>
    <arg name="world_name" default="empty.world"/> <!-- Note: the world_name is with respect to GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH environmental variable -->
    <arg name="respawn_gazebo" default="false"/>
    <arg name="use_clock_frequency" default="false"/>
    <arg name="pub_clock_frequency" default="100"/>
    <arg name="enable_ros_network" default="true" />

    <!-- set use_sim_time flag -->
    <param name="/use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)"/>

    <!-- set command arguments -->
    <arg unless="$(arg paused)" name="command_arg1" value=""/>
    <arg     if="$(arg paused)" name="command_arg1" value="-u"/>
    <arg unless="$(arg recording)" name="command_arg2" value=""/>
    <arg     if="$(arg recording)" name="command_arg2" value="-r"/>
    <arg unless="$(arg verbose)" name="command_arg3" value=""/>
    <arg     if="$(arg verbose)" name="command_arg3" value="--verbose"/>
    <arg unless="$(arg debug)" name="script_type" value="gzserver"/>
    <arg     if="$(arg debug)" name="script_type" value="debug"/>

    <!-- start gazebo server-->
    <group if="$(arg use_clock_frequency)">
      <param name="gazebo/pub_clock_frequency" value="$(arg pub_clock_frequency)" />
    </group>
    <group>
      <param name="gazebo/enable_ros_network" value="$(arg enable_ros_network)" />
    </group>
    <node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="$(arg script_type)" respawn="$(arg respawn_gazebo)" output="$(arg output)"
    args="$(arg command_arg1) $(arg command_arg2) $(arg command_arg3) -e $(arg physics) $(arg extra_gazebo_args) $(find bluebot)/worlds/$(arg world_name)" />

    <!-- start gazebo client -->
    <group if="$(arg gui)">
      <node name="gazebo_gui" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="gzclient" respawn="false" output="$(arg output)" args="$(arg command_arg3)"/>
    </group>

    <!-- Convert an xacro and put on parameter server -->
    <param name="robot_description" command="xacro $(find bluebot)/urdf/bluebot.xacro" />

  <!-- Spawn a robot into Gazebo -->
    <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-param robot_description -urdf -model bluebot" />

    <!-- <node name="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" output="screen"/> -->

  <!-- load the controllers -->
    <!-- <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
      output="screen" ns="/" args="left_front_wheel_joint_position_controller right_front_wheel_joint_position_controller 
      left_back_wheel_joint_position_controller right_back_wheel_joint_position_controller joint_state_controller"/> -->

    <!-- convert joint states to TF transforms for rviz, etc -->
    <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"
      respawn="false" output="screen">
      <remap from="/joint_states" to="/bluebot/joint_states" />
    </node>
  </launch>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. I have modified the tag of your question so it can be seen by the people who know about it, I hope this gets the question the proper attention.

Comment: I'd assume for the camera, you should change the roll pitch yaw of the origin of `<joint name="camera_joint" type="fixed">` by whichever 90 degree rotations you need to face the correct way & orientation.

Comment: Also, sorry for being lazy & not meticulously reading your files, but what's wrong with the wheels? Are they not visually being shown as part of the robot model? Are you looking for an odometry being published by them that you can't find? Or are you missing the frame transformations?

Comment: Hi @OriolAbril; Thank you for reply and modify. my problem regarding wheels was solved. the problem was considering about "convert joint states to TF transforms".

Comment: But the problem considering camera steel remains; I applied that transforms that you mentioned but it did not solve the problem.